# How do I get ActionBarSherlocks ViewPager

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm following the default Tab Navigation sample on the website:

```
package com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;

public class TabNavigation extends SherlockActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private TextView mSelected;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(SampleList.THEME); //Used for theme switching in samples
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.tab_navigation);
        mSelected = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

        getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            ActionBar.Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
            tab.setText("Tab " + i);
            tab.setTabListener(this);
            getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
        mSelected.setText("Selected: " + tab.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
    }
}
```

I've expanded modified fragments to include a WebView that loads a webpage. I noticed that whenever I switch tabs the webview has to reload. The fix for this is apparently to call setOffscreenPageLimit(2) on the viewpager where the tabs are kept. However I can't find out how to get the viewpager that ABS is using for my tabs?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that sample doesn't use a `ViewPager`; it only uses `Tab` navigation. Please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202834/android-tabs-sliding-how-do-i-implement-actionbarsherlock) post to learn how to implement "Tabs + Swipe" navigation using `ActionBarSherlock`.